# How to set a resource pool to failure/repair manually in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I would like to change the state of a resource pool manually using a button. However I cannot find the functions in help or code completion master, if there are any. Maybe you have ideas on  how to do it?
[image: code completion]